# Select color range and create vector map of that range

Tags: vector, colors, range

A question from a novice. Is it possible to design a tool to select color range and create a vector map within that given range to integrate into a flash tool? basically a feature that mimics the wand tool effect in photoshop, but creating a vector outline of the range selected. Any reading material to help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for either `2D segmentation`, if you want *all* the selected colors in the image to be selected, or `flood fill` if you want to find the region surrounding some initial point where all the colors are in the desired range.

When you say vector map, I imagine you mean the outline of the pixels to select.  In which case it's probably easier to find the pixels you want and then draw round then rather than explicitly creating a polygon to contain them.